# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') using fit from KNeighborsRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Prior to attempting the fit I have thoroughly cleaned my data frame and ensured that the entire data frame has no inf or NaN values and is composed of entirely non-null float64 values.  However, I still redundantly verified this using np.isinf(), df.isnull().sum() and df.info() methods.  All my research showed that others with the same issue had NaN, inf, or object data type in their data frame.  This is not so in my case. Lastly, I found a vaguely similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335489/error-in-fit-transform-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for-dt) which found a resolution using this code:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='ignore'))
```

This did not help in my situation.  How can I resolve this ValueError exception?

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read csv file and assign column names
headers=['symboling','normalized_losses','make','fuel_type','aspiration','num_of_doors',
         'body_style','drive_wheels','engine_location','wheel_base','length','width',
        'height','curb_weight','engine_type','num_of_cylinders','engine_size','fuel_system',
        'bore','stroke','compression_ratio','horsepower','peak_rpm','city_mpg','highway_mpg',
        'price']
cars = pd.read_csv('imports-85.data.txt', names=headers)

# Select only the columns with continuous values from - https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.names
continuous_values_cols = ['normalized_losses', 'wheel_base', 'length', 'width', 'height', 'curb_weight', 
                          'bore', 'stroke', 'compression_ratio', 'horsepower', 'peak_rpm', 'city_mpg', 'highway_mpg', 'price']
numeric_cars = cars[continuous_values_cols].copy()

# Clean Data Set by Convert missing values (?) with np.NaN then set the type to float
numeric_cars.replace(to_replace='?', value=np.nan, inplace=True)
numeric_cars = numeric_cars.astype('float')

# Because the column we're trying to predict is 'price', any row were price is NaN will be removed."
numeric_cars.dropna(subset=['price'], inplace=True)

# All remaining NaN's will be filled with the mean of its respective column
numeric_cars = numeric_cars.fillna(numeric_cars.mean())

# Create training feature list and k value list
test_features = numeric_cars.columns.tolist()
predictive_feature = 'price'
test_features.remove(predictive_feature)
k_values = [x for x in range(10) if x/2 != round(x/2)]

# Normalize columns
numeric_cars_normalized = numeric_cars[test_features].copy()
numeric_cars_normalized = numeric_cars_normalized/ numeric_cars.max()
numeric_cars_normalized[predictive_feature] = numeric_cars[predictive_feature].copy()


def knn_train_test(df, train_columns, predict_feature, k_value):

    # Randomly resorts the DataFrame to mitigate sampling bias
    np.random.seed(1)
    df = df.loc[np.random.permutation(len(df))]

    # Split the DataFrame into ~75% train / 25% test data sets
    split_integer = round(len(df) * 0.75)
    train_df = df.iloc[0:split_integer]
    test_df = df.iloc[split_integer:]

    train_features = train_df[train_columns]
    train_target = train_df[predict_feature]

    # Trains the model
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k_value)
    knn.fit(train_features, train_target)

    # Test the model & return calculate mean square error
    predictions = knn.predict(test_df[train_columns])
    print("predictions")
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_true=test_df[predict_feature], y_pred=predictions)
    return mse


# instantiate mse dict
mse_dict = {}

# test each feature and do so with a range of k values
# in an effot to determine the optimal training feature and k value
for feature in test_features:

    mse = [knn_train_test(numeric_cars_normalized,feature, predictive_feature, k) for k in k_values]
    mse_dict[feature] = mse

print(mse_dict)
```

Here's the full error trace back:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:395: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DATAQUEST\06_MachineLearning\01_ML_Fundamentals\06_GuidedProject_PredictingCarPrices\PredictingCarPrices.py", line 76, in <module>
    mse = [knn_train_test(numeric_cars_normalized,feature, predictive_feature, k) for k in k_values]
  File "C:\DATAQUEST\06_MachineLearning\01_ML_Fundamentals\06_GuidedProject_PredictingCarPrices\PredictingCarPrices.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
    mse = [knn_train_test(numeric_cars_normalized,feature, predictive_feature, k) for k in k_values]
  File "C:\DATAQUEST\06_MachineLearning\01_ML_Fundamentals\06_GuidedProject_PredictingCarPrices\PredictingCarPrices.py", line 60, in knn_train_test
    knn.fit(train_features, train_target)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 741, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 407, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 58, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Here's the code and output I used to verify that there are no NaN or inf values in my DataFrame:

```
# Verify data for NaN and inf
print(len(numeric_cars_normalized))
# 201

print(numeric_cars_normalized.info())
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# Int64Index: 201 entries, 0 to 204
# Data columns (total 14 columns):
# bore                 201 non-null float64
# city_mpg             201 non-null float64
# compression_ratio    201 non-null float64
# curb_weight          201 non-null float64
# height               201 non-null float64
# highway_mpg          201 non-null float64
# horsepower           201 non-null float64
# length               201 non-null float64
# normalized_losses    201 non-null float64
# peak_rpm             201 non-null float64
# price                201 non-null float64
# stroke               201 non-null float64
# wheel_base           201 non-null float64
# width                201 non-null float64
# dtypes: float64(14)
# memory usage: 23.6 KB
# None

print(numeric_cars_normalized.isnull().sum())
# bore                 0
# city_mpg             0
# compression_ratio    0
# curb_weight          0
# height               0
# highway_mpg          0
# horsepower           0
# length               0
# normalized_losses    0
# peak_rpm             0
# price                0
# stroke               0
# wheel_base           0
# width                0
# dtype: int64

# The loop below, essentially does the same as the above
# verification, but using different methods
# the purpose is to prove there's no nan or inf in my data set
index = []
NaN_counter = []
inf_counter = []
for col in numeric_cars_normalized.columns:
    index.append(col)
    # inf counter
    col_isinf = np.isinf(numeric_cars_normalized[col])
    if col_isinf.value_counts().index[0] == False:
        inf_counter.append(col_isinf.value_counts()[0])

    # nan counter    
    col_isnan = np.isnan(numeric_cars_normalized[col])
    if col_isnan.value_counts().index[0] == False:
        NaN_counter.append(col_isnan.value_counts()[0])

data_check = {'NOT_NaN_count': NaN_counter, 'NOT_inf_count': inf_counter}
data_verification = pd.DataFrame(data=data_check, index=index)
print(data_verification)

#                    NOT_NaN_count  NOT_inf_count
# bore                         201            201
# city_mpg                     201            201
# compression_ratio            201            201
# curb_weight                  201            201
# height                       201            201
# highway_mpg                  201            201
# horsepower                   201            201
# length                       201            201
# normalized_losses            201            201
# peak_rpm                     201            201
# price                        201            201
# stroke                       201            201
# wheel_base                   201            201
# width                        201            201
```

I may have found the problem, but still not sure how to fix it.

```
# Here's a another methodology for extra redudnant data checking
index = []
NaN_counter = []
inf_counter = []

for col in numeric_cars_normalized.columns:
    index.append(col)
    inf_counter.append(np.any(np.isfinite(numeric_cars_normalized[col])))
    NaN_counter.append(np.any(np.isnan(numeric_cars_normalized[col])))

data_check = {'Any_NaN': NaN_counter, 'Any_inf': inf_counter}
data_verification = pd.DataFrame(data=data_check, index=index)
print(data_verification)

                   Any_NaN  Any_inf
# bore                 False     True
# city_mpg             False     True
# compression_ratio    False     True
# curb_weight          False     True
# height               False     True
# highway_mpg          False     True
# horsepower           False     True
# length               False     True
# normalized_losses    False     True
# peak_rpm             False     True
# price                False     True
# stroke               False     True
# wheel_base           False     True
# width                False     True
```

So clearly I have inf in my DataSet, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it.

Comment: Did you also redundantly verify np.isnan ?

Comment: Please see my edit above where I attempt to verify there are no NaN or inf values in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that seems you are having comes from the permutation that you are doing, by commenting these two lines:

```
# np.random.seed(1)
# df = df.loc[np.random.permutation(len(df))]
```

This is because when you clean your data, you end up with only 201 rows from 204 of them. By debugging the dataframe that you provide to the knn function, you can find that indeed, three of the rows are now 'nan' for all columns once the numeric_cars_normalized have been permuted.

and rerunning the code, you will obtain results. But there is an additional change that you should do, as knn works better with arrays, you should change the dataframes (series) to values with the correct dimension and then operate with them. In your particular case, all of them are series, you can change them by:

```
series.values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Here is the knn function with all the changes:
    def knn_train_test(df, train_columns, predict_feature, k_value):

```
    #print(train_columns, k_value)
    # Randomly resorts the DataFrame to mitigate sampling bias
    #np.random.seed(1)
    #df = df.loc[np.random.permutation(len(df))]

    # Split the DataFrame into ~75% train / 25% test data sets
    split_integer = round(len(df) * 0.75)
    train_df = df.iloc[0:split_integer]
    test_df = df.iloc[split_integer:]

    train_features = train_df[train_columns].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    train_target = train_df[predict_feature].values.reshape(-1, 1)

    # Trains the model
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k_value)
    knn.fit(train_features, train_target)

    # Test the model & return calculate mean square error
    predictions = knn.predict(test_df[train_columns].values.reshape(-1,   1))
    print("predictions")
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_true=test_df[predict_feature], y_pred=predictions)
    return mse
```

With that, and if I get the correct input file, this is what I got:

```
predictions
{'normalized_losses': [100210405.34, 116919980.22444445, 88928383.280000001, 62378305.931836732, 65695537.133086421], 'wheel_base': [10942945.5, 31106845.595555563, 34758670.590399988, 29302177.901632652, 25464306.165925924], 'length': [71007156.219999999, 37635782.111111119, 33676038.287999995, 29868192.295918364, 22553474.111604933], 'width': [42519394.439999998, 25956086.771111108, 15199079.0744, 10443175.389795918, 8440465.6864197534], 'height': [117942530.56, 62910880.079999998, 41771068.588, 33511475.561224483, 31537852.588641971], 'curb_weight': [14514970.42, 6103365.4644444454, 6223489.0728000011, 7282828.3632653067, 6884187.4446913591], 'bore': [57147986.359999999, 88529631.346666679, 68063251.098399997, 58753168.154285707, 42950965.435555562], 'stroke': [145522819.16, 98024560.913333327, 61229681.429599993, 36452809.841224492, 25989788.846172832], 'compression_ratio': [93309449.939999998, 18108906.400000002, 30175663.952, 44964197.869387761, 39926111.747407407], 'horsepower': [25158775.920000002, 17656603.506666664, 13804482.193600001, 15772395.163265305, 14689078.471851852], 'peak_rpm': [169310760.66, 86360741.248888895, 51905953.367999993, 46999120.435102046, 45218343.222716056], 'city_mpg': [15467849.460000001, 12237327.542222224, 10855581.140000001, 11479257.790612245, 11047557.746419754], 'highway_mpg': [17384289.579999998, 15877936.197777782, 7720502.6856000004, 6315372.4963265313, 7118970.4081481481]}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution works, but I'm having trouble with why.  I'm not the type of person that is comfortable using code if I don't have a strong understanding of why it works.  I'll have to think on this and do some additional research.  This has created a bunch of follow up questions in my mind.

Comment: The code from the question has two problems that I see, one of them is that you are using directly pandas dataframes, when you do that and pass them to knn, it will try to operate with the dataframe or series directly. If you debug the code and check the dataframe.shape, you will see something like (201,) instead of (201,1) that you would expect. That could cause some trouble sometimes, so it is recommended that you use df.values.reshape(-1,1). values will transform them to numpy arrays, and reshape will make sure the shape of the array has 1 column and the -1 makes sure the rest are rows

Comment: the other problem is related to the data cleaning you did, it will remove some rows, as you pointed out, 3 of them, actually, but the index are still there, when you use permutation, python still finds them and then uses the index, that are the 'nan' that you removed previously. Another solution would be to reindex your dataframe so you make sure this does not happens, as an additional sanitization step, I didn't try it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification! Now I understand.